# Flutter OAuth2 with Custom Spring Boot Backend

Tags: android, spring-boot, flutter, flutter-web

I want to connect my flutter App to my Spring Boot Backend to let the user login in through OAuth2.

Spring Security Config:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import shoppinglist.service.configurations.security.oauth2userService.CustomOAuth2UserService;
import shoppinglist.service.configurations.security.oauth2userService.CustomOidcUserService;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private final CustomOidcUserService customOidcUserService;
    @Autowired
    private final CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(customOidcUserService).userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                    .and().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .and()
                )
                .logout(l -> l
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                );
    }
}
```

Calling "http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google" redirects the user to the "accounts.google.com" page, where the user then can proceed to choose their google account and login.

It works fine in the browser, but I can't find a way to do it with flutter.
The furthest I could get, was by using a library called "flutter_web_auth":

```
Future<void> oauth2(String provider) async {
    final String url = "http://10.0.2.2.nip.io:8080/oauth2/authorization/google";
    final String result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
        url: url, callbackUrlScheme: '10.0.2.2.nip:8080');
}
```

However the problem with this approach was the browser not closing after authentication.
The callbackUrlScheme is in the AndroidManifest.xml, too.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="10.0.2.2.nip:8080" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

(I need to use 10.0.2.2 because I am using a virtual android device and the nip.io is there to make google think the request is coming from a real server, so it allows oauth).

I would really appreciate your help and if you have other suggestions than flutter_web_auth please let me know.

And how do I then store the JSESSIONID?

Comment: Can you please share how you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but I suppose you need to indicate url scheme, not ip or web address. For example https:// - this is url scheme. For callback url scheme I suggest you to use your app bundle eg com.yourapp.bundle://

More you can read here, it is for xamarin, but behavior is the same:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=ios

[image]

Also, you should note, that your backend should use this callback url scheme within the response

P.S. easy peasy